# Persistent variable storage in Automator

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, automator

Is it possible to store a persistent value in an automator workflow (specifically for a service flow)?

It seems that regular automator variables [are not persistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048165/are-automator-variables-persistent); for instance trying to use [an applescript chunk which has a property](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.22/22.03/StoringandAccessingData/index.html) (which normally persists) does not actually persist the property in Applescript either (works in testing, but when you run the service the value doesn't persist).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

You can use script objects to store your data in an out of the way place.

[image: Automator]

```
on run
    -- Path of script which holds data
    set thePath to (path to desktop as text) & "myData.scpt"
    --set thePath to (path to preferences as text) & "myData.scpt" -- better

    script theData
        property xxx : missing value
    end script

    try
        set theData to load script file thePath
    on error
        -- On first run, set the initial value of the variable
        set theData's xxx to 5
    end try

    -- change the value of the variable
    set theData's xxx to (theData's xxx) + 1

    -- save your changes
    store script theData in file thePath replacing yes
    return theData's xxx
end run
```

Comment: +1 I hadn't thought of that and it's probably great for complex classes of data.

Comment: Thanks ... the script was adapted from an example in [AppleScript: The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596102111.do)

Comment: In case anyone else is learning applescript like me `replacing yes` mean overwrite if necessary