# Setting a launch variable with AppleScript in Automator

Tags: macos, bash, applescript, automator

I'm trying to set a variable using AppleScript from automator:

```
    do shell script "launchctl setenv LASTMAX \"" & today & "\""
```

I have a variable *today* that i want to assign to the variable LASTMAX

but when i check the property with echo $LASTMAX i keep getting the initial value,
even after i reboot.

How can i set variables with AppleScript?

Is there a different way to store persistant variables with automator?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use a script to store variables... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325386/persistant-variable-storage-in-automator/13328816#13328816

Comment: Thanks! That's just what i was hoping for

Comment: storing the script seems to only work the first time. It doesn't replace the property in the file once it is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use script objects to store your data in an out of the way place. 
[Persistant variable storage in Automator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325386/persistant-variable-storage-in-automator/13328816#13328816)

> storing the script seems to only work the first time.

When I paste the script refernced above into an Automator workflow and run the workflow several times, the returned value increments by one each time the script is run. Please post your code.