# Apple script Global variable not working when executing the service using a keyboard shortcut

Tags: applescript, automator

I have created a service in Automator to open a terminal using a different color schema everytime.

```
global terminalpos

on run {input, parameters}
    try
        get terminalpos
    on error
        set terminalpos to 0
    end try
    set colorsList to {"Pro", "Basic", "Grass", "Homebrew", "Man Page", "Novel", "Ocean", "Red Sands", "Silver Aerogel", "Solid Colors"}
    set listSize to count of colorsList
    if terminalpos is greater than or equal to listSize then
        set terminalpos to 0
    end if
    tell application "Terminal"
        set terminalpos to terminalpos + 1

        set default settings to settings set terminalpos

        do script ""
        activate
    end tell

end run
```

Inside automator it works fine.
but when I execute the service using a keyboard shortcut it does not work. seems that the global variable is being set every time.
Any ideas?

thank you

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't believe global variables persist across serial invocations of a script like that. Maybe write your variable in a file - example here... http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/sbrt/sbrt-09.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global variable are not "persistent" across launches of the application. Here's a link to an easy way to make data persist from an automator application. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325386/persistant-variable-storage-in-automator). Note that in an applescript application you can just use a "property" variable but they don't work with an automator application.

You can see the code from the link works without you doing anything. Set a value for the "first run" and then the saved data file is created automatically. I like the idea of setting the path for the saved data file to your preferences folder so it's out of the way and your automator app will work like every other app on your computer.